# Do BTC transactions also transfer funds of sister currencies that were forked from the BTC blockchain?

Tags: altcoin, blockchain-fork

If I mined some bitcoin before the bitcoin blockchain was forked and I transfer those bitcoins to another bitcoin wallet after the bitcoin blockchain was forked, does that also transfer the "sister" altcoin? Or does it only transfer the btc?

For example, let's say I mined a block on January 1st, 2010. I received 50 bitcoins as a reward, and I let them sit in cold storage for 10 years.

On January 1st, 2020, I want to sell my 50 bitcoins, so I buy a <s>pizza</s> pizza franchise for 50 BTC. I send the 50 BTC from my regular bitcoin wallet to the seller's bitcoin wallet.

Did I just transfer BCH (Bitcoin Cash) and BTG (Bitcoin Gold) -- two cryptocurrencies that forked off of the BTC blockchain in 2017 -- to the seller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, it depends. A fork could be constructed in such a way that transactions on one side of the chain can be "replayed" on the other side, in either direction, or in both.

This is however not the case for the forks you mention, or any high-profile ones that actually went through. So transacting after the fork on one side does not move coins on the other.